Where to make a request inside another request in clean architecture
I am relatively new with clean architecture, and I am facing an arhitecture problem that I don't know how to solve. I am making a GET request and based on the result of that request which returns a list, I am making another GET request for each element (20 elements in total), the thing is that I am doing this on the RepositoryImplementation, and I feel that this is making my app slower, I believe that I can solve the slow app issue with coroutines async() and awaitAll(), but since I am on the repository I can't make use of them, at least not without adding the withContext() block. Should I keep doing this on the repository, or should I go all the way up to my ViewModel and then go back to the repository again? Here my code:
 override suspend fun fetchPlayerMatches(playerId: Int) {
    val playerMatchesResponse = remoteDataSource.getPlayerRecentMatches(playerId)

    if (playerMatchesResponse.isSuccessful) {
        playerMatchesResponse.body()?.let { matchesList ->
            val matchDetails = matchesList.map { matchItem ->
                remoteDataSource.getPlayerRecentMatchesDetails(matchItem.matchId)
            }
            Log.i("TAG", "fetchPlayerMatches: ${matchDetails[0].matchId}")
            Log.i("TAG", "fetchPlayerMatches: ${matchDetails[0].duration}")
        }
    }
}


Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but... Can't your ORM give you all the data you need in one call? I thought that was the whole idea of DTOs... save on network trips and combine all relevant information in one answer.

Could you explain better? I mean, that would be great, save on network trips, but the info come separated, I have no make the first call to be able to make the second one

Currently you have getPlayerRecentMatches return the matchIds and then you need to make more calls passing those ids to get the details. Instead have getPlayerRecentMatches already return all the match details you really want. That way you only do 1 request, not 21. That one is bigger, but in the long run it may still be more efficient. This is the DTO idea. You may need to add a new endpoint just for this if other code also calls getPlayerRecentMatches and they don't want the extra data.

BTW, if your code is working and you want feedback on it, [codereview.se] may be a better fit.

Your code above is definitely wrong because you’re calling a blocking function inside a suspend function without wrapping it in a withContext.

@Tenfour04 what do you mean? So you suggest that I should wrap these requests inside a withContext() block? Could you share some expamples from other codes, I am not putting in doubt what you say, I am just trying to do the best for the app and learn in the proccess. Thanks in advance

Actually I’m looking at it again and maybe remoteDataSource.getPlayerRecentMatches() is a suspend function, not blocking? If so, your code above is okay.

@Tenfour04 they are all suspend fuctions from the viewModel up to the Retrofit call

Ok, then that’s fine. If the api doesn’t support batch calls, I think the best you can do is making all of these async calls and then do awaitAll, like you said.

About this logic being inside a Repository, I think it's ok as long as the data you are loading is really part of the Root Aggregate and not something that could be loaded into another abstraction. From the tiny bit of code you shared, I have the impression this is not the case and you could have a different abstraction that loads something like  PlayerRecentMatches. Then an Application Service can perform both calls and return them to the Controller.
On performance: loops that do IO are always troublesome. I assume you cannot modify the downstream API to load a batch of items in one go. If you can't, I think it's fine to use withContext() and fire a bunch of async requests (using Dispatchers.IO). Be sure you have an underlying connection pool that does those requests. If you can change the downstream API, create a new endpoint that returns all of the data you need.
I assumed you are doing (and familiar) with Domain-Driven Design as you mentioned using a Repository.
Edit
To add why loops that do IO are bad: they usually multiply the load on the downstream system. If the first system receives 100 requests per second (RPS), the downstream would need to handle 2000 RPS.
